# How to delete new-line character in asctime in QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I am converting time_t to human readable format. For this purpose I am using `asctime()` function. However it is also mentioned in c++ references.

> The string is followed by a new-line character ('\n') and terminated
>   with a null-character.

I know that I can delete '\n' character if I use char pointer. Such as;

```
char * str; 
str(strlen(str)-1) = '\0'; // repleacing new-line char to null-char
```

However how can I delete new-line characther in QString? Here is my example;

```
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    QString strList;
    rawtime = 1430687052;
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    strList += asctime(timeinfo);
```

EDIT:

I am creating report file, so that I have lots of '\n' char in my `QString`, thats why replacing all '\n' char to null pointer is not good idea.

Comment: Just use Qt only and problem solved (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 methods you will find useful:

`bool QString::endsWith (const QChar &c, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive ) const;`

`QString::remove(int position, int n);`

`QString& replace(const QRegExp &rx, const QString & after)`

Just remove last character and you're set. You can either use `remove()` or `replace()` with a regexp detecting `\n` at the end of the string.

Please be advised that internally `QString` uses 16-bit UTF character encoding.

If you like to operate on 8-bit characters, than you should use `QByteArray` and it's `QByteArray::remove(int position, int n)` method.

Comment: Thank you I used remove function defining QRegExp and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

I would use `QString::trimmed()` function to remove all trailing and leading whitespace characters, such as '\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', and ' '. I.e.:

```
strList = strList.trimmed();
```

Comment: As I said in EDIT section, I creating report txt and xls file, that's why deleting all char is not good idea.. My aim is deleting only last '\n' char in QString.

Comment: The function does not delete **all** chars, but all whitespece chars from the start and the end.

Answer (score 6):

Tell me why you are using C standard API when you use Qt?
You have great Qt API to handle dates.

```
QDateTime time;
uint rawtime = 1430687052;
time.setTime_t(rawtime);
QString humanDate = QLocale::system().toString(time, QLocale::ShortFormat);
```

---

To remove newline character in your concept just use [QString::trimmed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#trimmed) (removes from front and back any white characters).

Comment: actually I didnt know Qt has such ability.. I was writing application with limited time, thus I wrote it as fast as possible. +1 for  informing such ability.

Answer (score 2):

AS vahancho already pointed out. trimmed is probably the best way to go.

From the documentation of trimmed:

Unlike simplified(), trimmed() leaves internal whitespace alone.

So for example:

```
QString str = "  lots\t of\nwhitespace\r\n ";
str = str.trimmed();
// str == "lots\t of\nwhitespace"
```

Answer (score 0):

QString removes the `\0` for you, so the last character is your `\n`. That means you can also remove it simply by resizing your string to its current size -1.